# How to show Unicode characters in a QTextBrowser?

Tags: html, qt, unicode

I have an HTML file that contains `charset=utf-8` Unicode characters. I can read and show the content in a `QTextBrowser`. But the Unicode characters are not showing up properly. I think they are showing up using ANSI code equivalence which is very strange and unreadable.

How can I show the Unicode characters in a `QTextBrowser`?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a meta tag in your HTML file to specify that the contents are in UTF-8 format. Put the tag in header :

```
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
...
</head>
```

`QTextBrowser` would show the unicode characters properly.